# How to setup Python package config file using setup.cfg

Tags: python, package, setuptools, python-wheel

I am working on packaging a Python project that has the directory structure:

```
package-main (located on Desktop)
   - my_package
       - __init__.py
       - datasets
       - plot.py
       - shapefiles
           - __init__.py
           - shapefile1
                - shapefile1.shp
                - shapefiel1.dbf
                - (and 4 other file formats)
           - shapefile2
                - shapefile2.shp
                - shapefiel2.dbf
                - (and 4 other file formats)
       - utils.py
       - states.py
       - my_package.egg-info
   - LICENSE.txt
   - setup.cfg
   - README.md
   - tests
   - docs
   - pyproject.toml
   - dist
   - my_package.egg-info
```

I am running into a problem where when I upload the package `my_package` to testPyPI, and then download the package to my local machine using the command:

```
pip install my_package
```

it is not downloading all of the files.

When I create a `venv` to check the package files, and then go into the package files for the virtual environment it only shows:

```
my_package
my_package-0.1.1.dist-info
```

When I open up the `my_package` directory all I see is the following structure:

```
my_package
   - __init__py
   - __pychache__
   - plot.py
   - shapefiles
        - __init__.py
        - __pychache__
   - states.py
   - utils.py
```

**I have determined** that this must have something to do with how I setting up the `setup.cfg` file (perhaps I am not telling it to download all of the package files?

My current `setup.cfg` file looks like this:

```
[options]
install_requires =
    numpy
    geopandas
    matplotlib
python_requires = >=3.6

packages = find:
```

I have read the [documentation for setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html) here, but this does not fully clear things up for me. I need to tell the package to download the shape files as well.

I have seen multiple examples on how to do this with `setup.py`, but since it was advised on the [Python packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) that I do not use this method since its dynamic vs static, I have not been able to find any examples online of how to do this.

Any links to resources or examples would be greatly appreciated.

**Question:** How do I change the setup.cfg file to make sure that it downloads all of the files the package needs to function correctly?

**Edit:**

The `MANIFEST.in` file looks like this:

```
include my_package/shapefiles/shapefile1/*.shp
include my_package/shapefiles/shapefile1/*.dbf

include my_package/shapefiles/shapefile2/*.shp
include my_package/shapefiles/shapefile2/*.dbf
```

Comment: Please show your `MANIFEST.in`. -- Once you build your sdist and/or wheel, look inside them to check that all required files are present. -- Maybe look at [this](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html) if it helps (but use `setup.cfg` instead of `setup.py` as you area already doing).

Comment: So the `MANIFEST.in` file has all the correct paths for each of the files specified. When building the distribution it says that it is copying all six files that I would like to include. However, these files are never added to the distribution when it is done. Does this require some sort of reference to the `MANIFEST.in` file somewhere in the `setup.cfg` file or?

Comment: This is contradicting: "_it says that it is copying all six files_" and "_files are never added to the distribution_". I am not following. Also are you talking about the source distribution or the built distribution (wheel)? -- Anyway have you tried adding `include_package_data = True`? Otherwise there is no way to reference to `MANIFEST.in` in `setup.cfg` that I can think of.

Comment: That is just the output that it says when I run `python3 -m build`, it shows that it is copying the files, but they are not subsequently added to the `.tar` file in the `dist` folder after building the package.

Comment: Would it be easier to just start over and use a `setup.py` file instead?

Comment: Strange... -- There should be no need to switch to `setup.py`. -- Make sure your `setuptools` library is up to date. -- Between two build attempts, make sure to delete the `build` directory (and `dist` also maybe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `setuptools` docs on ["Configuring setup() using setup.cfg files"](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html?highlight=package_data), you could try the following:

```
[options]
...
include_package_data = True
...

[options.package_data]
* = *.dbf, *.shp, *.ext1, *.ext2, *.ext3, *.ext4
```

Comment: Yes, thank you this works. I was not including the `include_package_data = True` line.